# Not all code paths return a value and how to display methods in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, return-value

I'm trying to find the "Median","Maximum","Minimum","Average","Sum of numbers" and if there is any duplicates in the array. I ran into issues in the beginning when I made my methods and tried calling them in the main method. This produced "An object reference is required to access non-static member" so to combat this I made all the variables public static. Wasn't the best option but it worked. So I tackled the rest and when tried to display that I have duplicates I get "not all code paths return a value" So any help on how to fix this and any way to clean up the code will very helpful.

```
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;

    public class Test
    {
    public static int maxNum;
    public static int minNum;
    public static double avgNum;
    public static long sumNum;
    public static double median;

    public static int MaxNum(int[] randArray)
    {
        maxNum = randArray.Max();
        Console.WriteLine("This is the maximum value: " + maxNum);
        return maxNum;
    }
    public static int MinNum(int[] randArray)
    {
        minNum = randArray.Min();
        Console.WriteLine("This is the minimum value: " + minNum);
        return minNum;
    }
    public static long SumNum(int[]  randArray)
    {
        for(int x =0; x < randArray.Length;x++)
            sumNum = sumNum +randArray[x];
        Console.WriteLine("This is the sum of values: " + sumNum);
        return sumNum;
    }
    public static double Average(int[]  randArray)
    {
        avgNum = randArray.Average();
        Console.WriteLine("This is the average of the values: " + avgNum);
        return avgNum;
    }
    public static int GetMedian(int[] randArray)
    {

        int size = randArray.Length;
        int mid = size / 2;
        double median = (size % 2 != 0) ? (double)randArray[mid] : ((double)randArray[mid] + (double)randArray[mid - 1]) / 2;
        Console.WriteLine("This is the median value:" + median);
        return Convert.ToInt32((median));
    }
    public static bool ContainDups(int[] randArray)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < randArray.Length; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < randArray.Length; j++)
            {
                if (randArray [i] == randArray [j])
                    return true;
            }

        }
            return false;
    }        
     public static int ShowDups(int[] randArray)
     {
         if(ContainDups(randArray) == true)
        {
                Console.WriteLine("Contains duplicate numbers");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No duplicate numbers");
        }
  }
      public static void Main()
    {
        int[] randArray = new int[1000];
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < randArray.Length; i++)
        {
            randArray[i] = r.Next();
        }
        Array.Sort(randArray);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            //  Console.WriteLine(","+randArray[i]);
        }

        MaxNum(randArray);
        MinNum(randArray);
        SumNum(randArray);
        Average(randArray);
        GetMedian(randArray);
        ContainDups(randArray);
        ShowDups(randArray);


    }
}
```

Comment: you are not returning anything in static int ShowDups(int[] randArray)

Comment: and to "show methods" you'll have to create an instance of the class test in your main method.. something like Test test = new Test()... and then test.MaxNum(randArray)

Comment: It doesn't look like any of these methods need to return anything, perhaps return void or return the string of your Console.WriteLine? Also `ContainDups(randArray) == true` is equivalent to `ContainDups(randArray)`

Comment: [return (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx)

Comment: @fabricio changed all as you said and implemented the instance and all is working now!

Comment: @AWinkle changed works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if all the class members are static, just make the class to be static instead .

Secondly, if you have no intention to return value in your function and just write to console, then use `void` instead of `int`

Answer (score 2):

This method `public static int ShowDups(int[] randArray)` doesn't return anything. You just write to te console a message and you don't return an `int` as it is expected by the signature of your method.